# POST Request Works in Postman but not properly with RestTemplate - SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-resttemplate

I'm using `RestTemplate` to get the response body was encrypted or else not properly showing (it's working properly till yesterday, but today this problem occurred without changing any code). But when I hit the API in `Postman` it's getting the proper response body (in XML type content).

I have no idea for this issue because that code worked properly till yesterday.

Why does this happen? And how does `Postman` show proper response and `RestTemplate` showing another type?

Note: attach image for your refernce

[image]

My code:

```
String xml = jaxbObjectToXML(createSRINTOSSet);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

// create headers
headers.add("MAXAUTH", auth);
headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);

try {
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(xml, headers);
    response = restTemplate.postForEntity(maximoIntegrationURI, request, String.class);
```

Comment: Can you show how the response body looks like?